# LINQ Query comprehensions - why is System.Linq namespace required?

Tags: c#, linq

A coworker of mine and I were having a discussion today about Linq. In particular, that the System.Linq namespace needs to be included (via usings) before the query comprehensions can be used. I was thinking that this is done to make it less likely to use a non-Linq extension method by mistake, but we never came to a conclusion. Why should/shouldn't the System.Linq namespace be included when using query comprehensions?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't a real question. The logical conclusion of this line of reasoning is that we shouldn't have to write any `using` statements ever; the compiler should just figure it all out.

Comment: @Yuck - Perhaps this would be a better world if it did (I know SO would have about have as many issues to solve).

Comment: @M.Babcock: No, because then we run into namespace collision, intellisense pollution, etc. The closest thing you can get to this is to have tools such as ReSharper/CodeRush/etc. automatically place the using statements for you if there isn't any ambiguity.

Comment: @m-y - I understand the issues (and I was only half serious), one can dream though.

Comment: @recursive: you and OP are probably talking about different usages of `using` (pun intended).

Comment: @Yuck: I realized my mistake too late.  I still think it's a different case.  There can be name collisions across namespaces, but query comprehensions always refer to System.Linq.

Comment: I think you actually don't have to include it (need to try) - if you implement correct methods (like Select) yourself it should just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound obvious, but the `System.Linq` namespace should be included when we intend to use LINQ facilities provided by the Framework. But nothing prevents us from using our own ones, and the compiler doesn't mind.

For instance, the following (silly, but complete!) code fragment compiles and runs perfectly well:

```
// no usings at all
static class DumbLinq
{
    static int Select(this int i, System.Func<int, int> f)
    {
        // actually, our Select is a negation operator in disguise
        return -i;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        var j = from n in i
                select n;
        System.Console.WriteLine(j); // prints -10
    }
}
```

The compiler simply transforms the query comprehension syntax into the "fluid" syntax before it compiles the code. Once it finds appropriate methods to use, it proceeds as usual. By `using` `System.Linq` we ensure that the compiler will find the classes and interfaces that support queries that use LINQ, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks - I tried to write something like this, but I think that my method signature wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to include System.Linq for query comprehensions to work - see example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SelectQuery
{

    internal static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<int> Select(this int[] items, Func<int, int> selector)
        {
            return items;

        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] data = new[] { 1, 2, 34 };

            var result = from v in data select v;
            foreach (var i in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Linq libraries are exactly that, a library.  If you don't need it, then don't include it in the memory space, or reference the DLL.

But the linq functionality basically runs against `IEnumerable<T>`, they are just methods, with a little sugar from the C# compiler when you want to use the query syntax.

Comment: It's not a question of including a reference.  The contents of `System.Linq` are in the assembly System.Core.  It's a question of including the namespace via `using`.

Comment: Yes it is.  The System.Linq namespace contains method calls that work against and sometimes return IEnumerable<T>.  The reason they add the using statements is to deal with the issue of breaking changes.  If you implement a "Select" method in legacy code and now Linq is magically added into your default namespace, then old code suddenly breaks after upgrade :(